# Issue with my foreach loop

Tags: php, forms, validation, foreach

So i am trying to validate a form for php.

my contact form is your typical form

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
   <table class="contact">
     <tr>
      <th>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      </th>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
     <th>
     <label for="email">Email</label>
   </th>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
   </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
   <th>
   <label for="message">Message</label>
   </th>
    <td>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </td>
   </tr>    
 </table>   
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
```

now i want to add the php validation to this so i created the following:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$errors = array();

$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$message    = $_POST['message'];

if(empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Please fill out all the required forms!';
} else {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry please enter a valid email address';
    }
    if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, name must contain only letters!';
    }
}
print_r ($errors);
```

Now i try to print this out and the array shows the data being imputed into fields, and all the validations work properly. The issue i have is the next step where i add the php to echo out the array in a list.

The code i added above the form was a foreach loop that was suppose to list the error that was shown for any failure of validation:

```
<?php 
if (empty($errors) === false) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach($errors as $error) {
echo '<li>' , $error ,'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}   
?>
```

But now the issue is this: Everytime now i fill out the form the errors don't produce a list they just produce the original array is if the foreach is not being seen.

Any suggestions or help would be great !

thanks guys,

Comment: Laying out a form with a html table is not "typical". Well...maybe a decade ago. :)

Comment: You should change the `=== false` to what popnoodles has or use !empty instead.

Comment: The thing about forms in tables is that it's less markup to align your inputs than going another way about it, and when do you not want the fields to behave in a tabular way? Not using tables for layout is absolutely right, but not doing it for forms that have input after input that all need lining up nicely, it's like cutting off your nose to spite your face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (count($errors)) echo '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $errors).'</li></ul>';
else echo 'No errors';
```

With this are you seeing "No errors"?

Aside, there is no need to do this

```
if(empty($name) === true)
```

empty($name) is either true or false. No need to then compare it to true.

```
if(empty($name))
```

is perfectly fine, otherwise it's like asking

```
if ((count(12)>0)==true)!=false)
```

which would be ridiculous. And actually

```
if(empty($name.$email.$message))
```

is far fewer characters, giving the same result as

```
if(empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true)
```